# Getting Error in PHP ActiveRecord\Config::initialize

Tags: php, activerecord, composer-php

While i'm trying to execute these codes, php encountered a parse error. Why it is happening? I provide the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: `function` not **fucntion**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the spelling function

Comment: My mistake :V Thanks